# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (file path): open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android

I follow the eclipse example code,
I added

> "uses-permission" at manifest

too,

but it didn't work
this is i followed code

@java@

/*This activity displays the gallery image picker.
 It displays the image that was picked.
 author ITCuties
*/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS = 1;


private Button button; 
private ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);


    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));


        cursor.close();
        Bitmap thumb = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        image.setImageBitmap(thumb);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Create the Intent for Image Gallery.
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    // Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS to handle back the results when image is picked from the Image Gallery.
    startActivityForResult(i, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);

}
```

}

and

@layout xml@

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     />
```

Comment: WHat's version of android? Could you upload androidmanifest?

Comment: i solve this problem.

Comment: sorry to guys solving this problem.